# Why in uniformly convex Banach space every non empty, closed, convex subset contains a unique element of smallest norm?

Tags: functional-analysis

In Hilbert space every non empty, closed, convex subset contains a unique element of smallest norm. Why is that true also in Banach space which is uniformly convex?

(normed space which is uniformly convex is a space in which for all sequences $\{x_n\}$, $\{y_n\}$ s.t $||x_n||,||y_n||\leq 1$ exists: if $\lim_n||x_n+y_n||=2$ then  $\lim_n||x_n-y_n||=0$.)

I thought of defining $a=\inf\{||x|| : x\in X\}$, so exists a  sequence $\{x_n\}$ s.t $\lim_n||x_n||=\inf||x_n||=a$ and then to show that $\{x_n\}$ is a Cauchy sequence and it's limit is the element we are looking for, but i didn't manage to prove that it is Cauchy.

Comment: That's what you do... Here's a link to a complete proof: <a>http://books.google.com/books?id=5IAWL8MUGtQC&pg=PA28&lpg=PA28&dq=Banach+space++minimal+norm+uniformly+convex&source=bl&ots=9wLNB9QKLM&sig=om4bvnyrNsNSrXyU4g7OIWtIxzM&hl=en&</a>ei=09K6Tpq2NOry2QWandi2Bw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=7&ved=0CFMQ6AEwBg#v=onepage&q=Banach%20space%20%20minimal%20norm%20uniformly%20convex&f=false

Comment: The idea is that uniformly convex implies that if $\|x_n\|$ and $\|x_m\|$ are close enough to $a$ and $\|(x_n + x_m)/2\| \ge a$, $\|x_n - x_m\|$ must be close to 0.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a particular case [Ex 3.32](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4412982/projection-is-uniformly-continuous-on-bounded-sets-of-a-uniformly-convex-banach) in Brezis's book of *Functional Analysis*. In fact, consider the projection of $0\in E$ into $C$.

> Let $(E, |\cdot|)$ be a uniformly convex Banach space and $C \subset E$ a nonempty.
>
> 1. Prove that for every $x \in E$,
>    $$
>    \inf _{y \in C}|x-y|
>    $$
>    is achieved by some unique point in $C$, denoted by $P x$.
> 2. Prove that every minimizing sequence $\left(y_{n}\right)$ in $C$ converges strongly to $P x$.
> 3. Prove that the map $x \mapsto P x$ is continuous from $E$ strong into $E$ strong.
> 4. More precisely, prove that $P$ is uniformly continuous on bounded subsets of $E$.